# lm-sensors issues with sensors

Tags: 14.04, configuration, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

When I configure any machine with Ubuntu I set up lm-sensors to work. I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I've set up the sensors as [the official page says](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) (This is how I do every time).

Well, before I installed 14.04 over 12.04 I would get all this data:

```
/etc/mrtg/cfg/mrtg-scripts$ sensors
    adt7490-i2c-0-2e
    Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at f000
    in0:          +1.12 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.31 V)
    Vcore:        +1.09 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.99 V)
    +3.3V:        +3.25 V  (min =  +2.96 V, max =  +3.61 V)
    +5V:          +5.03 V  (min =  +4.48 V, max =  +5.50 V)
    +12V:        +11.90 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max = +15.69 V)
    in5:          +2.10 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.48 V)
    fan1:        1312 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
    temp1:        +38.5°C  (low  =  +5.0°C, high = +65.0°C)
                           (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +66.0°C)
    M/B Temp:     +39.8°C  (low  =  +5.0°C, high = +65.0°C)
                           (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +66.0°C)
    temp3:        +42.2°C  (low  =  +5.0°C, high = +65.0°C)
                           (crit = +70.0°C, hyst = +66.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +59.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +55.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +55.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +57.0°C  (high = +74.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +60.5°C
```

Now it's not showing the adt7490-i2c-0-2e chip.

Before reinstalling Ubuntu I updated BIOS to solve a problem with kingston 1666Mhz memory modules that my DP45SG Intel motherboard has.

I've checked that in Hardware Monitoring Health Information in BIOS, all the temperatures, fan speed and voltages are showing normally.

BIOS VERSION: SGP4510H.76A.0125.2010.0121.1927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added to `/etc/modules` a new line:

```
i2c_i801
```

restarted `kmod`:

```
sudo service kmod restart
```

And now its working!